# Python: modified list after enumerate(list)

Tags: python

Atm I'm trying to get into python and watched a video from Corey Schafer on youtube. In this video he used the *enumerate* function to iterate through a list. After I tried it out by myself I recognized that my list reduces to last item. It's even not a list anymore

I don't understand why this happens.
Thats my code:

```
courses = ['History', 'Math', 'Physics', 'CompSci']
courses2 = ['Art', 'Education']
courses.extend(courses2)

print(courses) # return ['History', 'Math', 'Physics', 'CompSci', 'Art', 'Education']


for index, courses in enumerate(courses):
    print(index, courses) # return the expeted result 0 History, 1 Math...

print(courses) # return Eductation
```

Thanks for help in advance! :)

Comment: Assign diffrent varible in loop ``for index, course in enu..``. Because you programme will remember the last courses.

Comment: `for index, courses in enumerate(courses):` should be `for index, course in enumerate(courses):` - otherwise you overwrite `courses` in your iteration.

Answer (score 3):

You used `courses` as your iteration variable, so you replaced the original `courses` `list` with each value in it as you went. Use `course` as the name and your code works. `enumerate` itself cached a reference to the original `list` in `courses` so the change didn't affect the loop itself.

```
# Fixed loop
for index, course in enumerate(courses):
    print(index, course) # return the expeted result 0 History, 1 Math...
```

Comment: Oh thanks for your nearly instant reply! I'tried it out and it works fine! Thanks alot for explanation and solution!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're using the same variable `courses` twice in different contexts. When you print the variable in the end of the file, you get the last item of the list from the loop. Change your loop to this and try again:

```
for index, course in enumerate(courses):
    print(index, course)
```